# Is there a way to override Android Gallery widget default animation, e.g. the interpolator

Tags: android, widget, gallery, interpolation

I need to have a custom interpolator for the Gallery widget. I checked the documentation and source codes but couldn't find anywhere to specify/override the default animation behavior. Maybe some of you might know?

Thanks!

UPDATE: i ended up just extend Gallary widget and implemented my own animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

i ended up just extend Gallary widget and implemented my own animation

Comment: You could post here an example.