# Android Gallery Transition Between Images

Tags: android, image, animation, gallery, transition

I have a gallery that shows the images of some playing cards. Each card is separated by 20dp.

When I move from one image to the next, the gallery scrolls slightly beyond the next image, and subsequently corrects itself back to the image.

Another issue, almost certainly related, is that the images are not scrolling past out of view cleanly. The images appear to be trying to either snap into full view, or to snap out of view entirely, causing manual scrolling to jerk the images side to side as I scroll.

Any idea what may be causing this?

Here is a screen recording of it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mvj4_48AW5Q&feature=youtu.be

Here is the xml for the gallery:

```
<Gallery
android:id="@+id/gallery"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp" 
android:scrollbars="none" 
android:layout_below="@+id/button1" 
android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
android:spacing="20dp" 
android:animationDuration="3000"
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had to extend gallery, I think the issue had something to do with a timer that I had on screen. The issue is discussed further here: http://www.unwesen.de/2011/04/17/android-jittery-scrolling-gallery/

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.Gallery;


public class CustomGallery extends Gallery {

private long mLastScrollEvent;
private float mFlingMultiplier;

public CustomGallery(Context context) {
    super(context);
}
public CustomGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
public CustomGallery(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
  long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
  if (Math.abs(now - mLastScrollEvent) > 500 * mFlingMultiplier) {      
      super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);    
  }
}


@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
    float distanceY)
{
  mLastScrollEvent = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
  mFlingMultiplier = 1;
  return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
}



@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    mFlingMultiplier = Math.abs(velocityX/100);
    return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that is being caused by the animation interpolator that the Gallery sets on the slide animation. The overshoot interpolator will cause that behavior.

If you want to override it, I'm not sure how easy that will be. I did a quick search, but I couldn't find anything that would let you easily override the default interpolator for the Gallery. The only thing I did find was [this post with someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489744/is-there-a-way-to-override-android-gallery-widget-default-animation-e-g-the-in) who seemed to have success by creating a new Gallery class that extends the Android Gallery class in order to override the default interpolator.